# Issue with calculation

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Can anyone see if there's problem with the way i handle the calculation below? I seemed to be getting "You scored 0" at runtime even when the answer is actually correct.

```
- (void)countGain{
int gain = 0;
int percentage;
if ([answer objectForKey:@"1"] == [usrAnswer objectForKey:@"1"]) {
    gain += 1;

}
percentage = (gain / 10) * 100;

NSString *scored = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"You scored %d",percentage];
score.text = scored;
rangenans.text = [answer objectForKey:@"1"];

[scored release];

}
```

Comment: What type is [answer objectForKey:@"1"] ?

Comment: Surely that is what they type os answer is - what do you put in answer?

Comment: Ah I see from another answer they are NSStrings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the point doing:

```
percentage = (gain / 10) * 100;
```

Use

```
percentage = gain * 10;
```

Rest looks good. You shouldn't divide integers. What if you get 3/10 and this is int value?

In condition change

```
if([answer objectForKey:@"1"] == [usrAnswer objectForKey:@"1"])
```

To:

```
if([[answer objectForKey:@"1"] isEqualToString:[usrAnswer objectForKey:@"1"]])
```

Comment: i did that... clicked and still get 0 :(

Comment: Whats return that method: [answer objectForKey:@"1"] ? int? NSSsting? I know it is a record in NSDictionary, but what you put in there?

Comment: `NSString *answer1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:[qnBlock objectAtIndex:1]];`
    `answer = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];`
   `[answer setObject:answer1 forKey:@"1"];`
Just NSStrings

Comment: `NSString *userChoice = [NSString stringWithFormat:label2.text];`
        `[usrAnswer setObject:userChoice forKey:@"1"];`
        `userAnswer.text = [usrAnswer objectForKey:@"1"];`
Compared to also NSString...

Comment: I've got a nudging feeling its something to do with
`NSString *userChoice = [NSString stringWithFormat:label2.text];`

Comment: It worked!!! Thank you so much... Btw, is there an equivalent comparator for integers and other types of variables?

Comment: No, string is specific. integers, float will work with "==". For BOOL you could use if(something). YES - enter, NO - leave.  Glad I can help ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is integer arithmetic. Try:

```
percentage = gain * 10;
```

or

```
percentage = (gain * 10 ) / 100;
```

or

```
percentage = ((float)gain / 10) * 100;
```

Note that in any of the above, you only have 10 options for the "percentage", so `percentage = gain * 10;` is the simpler.

Comment: @Mark the `gain * 100` was a typo :)

Comment: I've just got a nudging feeling its something to do about the
`NSString *userChoice = [NSString stringWithFormat:label2.text];`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to compare NSStrings and == compares the assresses of strings. You want to compare their values

e.g.

```
NSString *correct = @"Yes";
NSString *answer = ..... from some entry;
```

Then these two NSStrings will point to different bits of memory.

to compre with the user replied you need to compare values using the [isEqualToString:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-isEqualToString_) method

e.g.
`gain += [correct isEqualToString:answer] ? 1 : 0;`

In your code == failed each time so gain was always 0. So the int division problem never occureed - but it would have when gain became 1 etc.

Comment: so in my case it should be something like
`gain +=[answer objectForKey:@"1"] isEqualToString:[usrAnswer objectForKey:@"1"]] ? 1: 0;`
Is that correct?

Comment: Yes but you need another [ after += (although I would tend to use a few local variables here so you can see any issues in a debugger